# Как задать диапазон и передать индексу dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Есть, список значений индекса полученный из dataframe  : list_data = [5,10]

Нужно, из каждого элемента списка list_data сформировать такой диапазон, для значения '5' : 2-6, а для '10' : 7-11, где начало -3 к значению элемента списка, а для конца +1 к значению элемента списка.

Полученные диапазоны передать датафрейму, где каждый элемент диапазона является индексом для этого дата фрейма, для заполнения атрибута датафрейма.

Псевдо пример:

```
df
list_data = [5,10]
for i in list_data:
 df['att1'].loc[list_data(i).shift(-3) between list_data(i).shift(1)]=='Key_val'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из вашего примера и пояснения к нему стало понятно, что индексы вы должны строить по значениям списка list_data, причем и количество элементов в нем и сами эти значения могут быть различны (иначе задавайте из статично да и дело с концом). Итак.

```
list_data = [5,10]
new_index=[]
for i in list_data:
    for j in range (i-3,i+2):
      new_index.append(j)  
print(new_index)
```

Для вашего примера получаем

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Теперь список new_index вы хотите использовать как индекс для некоего датафрейма.
Создаем датафрейм, в котором заготавливаем столько строчек, сколько у вас значений в созданном индексе, и используем созданный список для создания индекс-меток. Строки пока вообще не задаем, как и сами значения в датафрейме:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(index=new_index)
```

Ну, а дальше -  создавайте колонки, заполняйте нужными значениями, манипулируйте с датафреймом так, как вам надо. Надеюсь с этим у вас трудностей нет.

Comment: благодарю за ответ. Наверно, я не правильно передал вопрос. Думаю, вопрос звучит так : Как передать список значений в оператор .loc ?

Comment: Первоначальный список   [5,10] это уже подмножество существующего дата фрейма образованного путём  .index.tolist() к которому эти адреса надо передать , а также переменные смещения при условии будут меняться...

Comment: И что? Как происхождение списка влияет на алгоритм. А если "переменные смещения" будут меняться -  то надеюсь вы понимаете, что приведенный фрагмент кода надо оформить как функцию и указанные значения передавать в нее как параметр. Впрочем -  об этом в исходном сообщении не было ни слова. А на форуме действует правило -  "одна тема - один вопрос". Поэтому если у вас есть модификация к вашему вопросу -  оформляйте ее как другой вопрос. А мой ответ касался в точности того, что вы сформулировали изначально в вопросе.